# Hyperref does not quite keep up with the kern applied to the linked text

Tags: spacing, hyperref, links

Is there a way to have `hyperref` shift the boxes when a kern is applied to the text to be linked to?

[image]

There does seem to be an attempt to keep up with the kern, but seems to be quite a bit off?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{$\!$TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{$\!\!$TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{$\!\!$TeX.SE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The link box follows the bounding box. You can easily see it if you add a \fbox around the the \href. How should hyperref know that you move the text outside the box with a negative space?

Comment: don't you want the negative space before the `\href` not inside it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Good point. But, wondering why there is _any_ shifting of the box then?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well, that is rather complicated in my actual use case as the text (with the kern to be applied) comes from quite a few macro levels above so will need a lot of changes to  separate the negative spacing and the text to be applied.  Was hoping that there was a way to move the `hyperref` box itself.

Comment: You mean on the right? You are making the bounding box smaller with the negative space. This is not specific to links. Try out as I suggested with \fbox.

Comment: as Ulrike says, hyperref is doing nothing here, it's just that you are hiding the width of the text with negative space. of course if the initial space is some expected markup (hopefully not `$\!$` !!) you could define `\href[zzz}` to see if zzz starts with the negative space command and if so do `\negspace\originalhref{zzz-without\negspace}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I did try your suggestion and saw that the `\fbox` also shifted and that hyperref is centered within that. However, the `\fbox` does cover the desired area but `hyperref` does not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yeah, that is what I'll need to do based on the comments. If one of you want to add that as an answer I'll take my loses and move on. :-(.  I just never notices this issue until now.

Comment: With \fbox you get the additional space of \fboxsep, try out \fboxsep=0pt or larger negative space. Imho there is nothing in the pdf specification to make the link area larger.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: ok, I see what you mean. The shift is only on the right. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{$\!$TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{$\!\!$TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{$\!\!$TeX.SE}



\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\frame{TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\frame{$\!$TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\frame{$\!\!$TeX.SE}
\par\hspace*{2.0cm}\frame{$\!\!$TeX.SE}



\end{document}
```

[image]

hyperef doesn't see the negative space at all, just as for `\frame` (a tighter version of `\fbox`)  if you add negative space the effective width of the text is reduced.